# CakeDC Users Plugin - Is there a way to change the user id?

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with the CakeDC Users Plugin (https://github.com/CakeDC/users). When you add a user, it adds them to the database with a very long 'id' field (ie. 5092b9c5-1734-4d1f-a98b-210b46204441).

I tried going through the code to remove that, so it just auto-increments after the last id, but I can't find where to change.

Does anyone know what line(s) need to be changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely just your table structure.  CakePHP automatically uses [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) when you set your "id" field to CHAR(36).

Just change that field to int(10) auto-increment, and it should be back to "normal".  (though, personally I'm a fan of UUIDs).

Just remember - any fields that reference user_id must also have the same field type.

Comment: Yep! That was it. I didn't notice because the table was baked from the plugin code. Thanks so much!

Comment: Not a problem - glad to help.